# Onetone YouTube Background Video Not Playing in Safari or IE11

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, video, youtube, safari

I am using the Onetone (not pro) Wordpress theme, and am attempting to get the Youtube Background Video function to work.  It works great in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari or IE11.  Does anyone know if this function is supported by Safari and/or IE11, or how to make it work?  Thanks!